# Scala : Syntactic Sugar

Tags: scala, akka, akka-typed

I have been scratching my head to understand how to read this function:

```
private def greeterBehavior(currentGreeting: String): Behavior[Command] =
    Actor.immutable[Command] { (ctx, msg) =>
      msg match {
        case WhoToGreet(who) =>
          greeterBehavior(s"hello, $who")
        case Greet =>
          println(currentGreeting)
          Actor.same
      }
    }
```

Questions:

1 ) function takes string and returns `Behavior[Command]` . ( understood)
But ..  what is `Actor.immutable[Command]`  ? 
Is this a type casting ? or is it an object ?

2)  if I have to understand such syntax what is the best place or book I can refer?

Comment: The prose-documentation suggests that this should be `akka.typed.scaladsl.Actor`-object. However: 1) I couldn't find any scaladocs online. 2) There isn't even `Actor.scala` in [the package `akka-actor-typed/src/main/scala/akka/actor/typed/scaladsl`](https://github.com/akka/akka/tree/master/akka-actor-typed/src/main/scala/akka/actor/typed/scaladsl) on github. I personally find the state of documentation (or rather, lack thereof), and the organization of the package a bit astonishing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`immutable` is a method on `Actor`, which takes in a generic type parameter, in this case that type is `Command`.

Any intro to Scala material worth reading should cover generics.  "Programming in Scala" and "Scala for the Impatient" are both popular.

Comment: How great that there is just one single `Actor` object in the entire universe, and that there are no problems at all finding `akka.typed.scaladsl.Actor` in the scaladocs...

Comment: @AndreyTyukin yeah, I don't know akka at all, but it still took way too long for me to find the correct `Actor`, and I didn't even see it in the scaladoc.  It could definitely be improved

Comment: @One Looks like valid scala to me, although the awkward formatting makes it a little hard to tell (looks like you included the repl responses as well, instead of just code).  I'm not sure how it relates to your question or my answer though.  Could you clarify what you are looking to understand?

Comment: Correction : Is this a correct example in plain scala ?

`def abc(x : Int => Int) : Int =  { x(10)}`
`def one(a :Int) = abc { (x:Int) => x+a
}`

`var f1 = one(10)`

Comment: @ Andrey Tyukin . Could you please help me find API documentation for this ? I could not find scala type help for given package/object.

Comment: @One It is valid Scala but you presumably already know this since you wrote and successfully ran it.  So again, my question is: what are you trying to clarify and how does it relate to your question or my answer?  In particular, your methods are not using any generic type which is what I thought was causing your confusion.  If it is actually the use of lambda expressions and passing functions as arguments to methods, then yes I think your example demonstrates it nicely.  You can try calling `abc` with different functions to see how it can be useful.

Answer (score 2):

To address the comments regarding the location of the API documentation for `Actor.immutable`:

As the Akka [documentation](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/typed/actors.html#actors) clearly states, the Akka Typed API is still in flux:

> This module is currently marked as [may change](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/common/may-change.html) in the sense of being the subject of active research. This means that API or semantics can change without warning or deprecation period and it is not recommended to use this module in production just yet—you have been warned.

Apparently you're using a pre-2.5.10 version of Akka: the `Actor` object was removed from the Akka Typed module in version 2.5.10.

- From [Akka 2.5.2](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.5.2/akka/typed/scaladsl/Actor$.html#immutable[T](onMessage:(akka.typed.scaladsl.ActorContext[T],T)=%3Eakka.typed.Behavior[T]):akka.typed.scaladsl.Actor.Immutable[T]) to [Akka 2.5.8](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.5.8/akka/typed/scaladsl/Actor$.html#immutable[T](onMessage:(akka.typed.scaladsl.ActorContext[T],T)=%3Eakka.typed.Behavior[T]):akka.typed.scaladsl.Actor.Immutable[T]), there was an `akka.typed.scaladsl.Actor.immutable` method.
- In Akka 2.5.9, the [`Actor.immutable`](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.5.9/akka/actor/typed/scaladsl/Actor$.html#immutable[T](onMessage:(akka.actor.typed.scaladsl.ActorContext[T],T)=%3Eakka.actor.typed.Behavior[T]):akka.actor.typed.scaladsl.Actor.Immutable[T]) method moved to the `akka.actor.typed` package.
- In Akka 2.5.10, the `akka.actor.typed.Actor` object was removed. This object is still absent in 2.5.11 and 2.5.12 (the current version of Akka at the time of this writing).

Here is the Scaladoc for the last version of `Actor.immutable` from [Akka 2.5.9](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.5.9/akka/actor/typed/scaladsl/Actor$.html#immutable[T](onMessage:(akka.actor.typed.scaladsl.ActorContext[T],T)=%3Eakka.actor.typed.Behavior[T]):akka.actor.typed.scaladsl.Actor.Immutable[T]):

```
def immutable[T](onMessage: (ActorContext[T], T) => Behavior[T]): Immutable[T]
```

> Construct an actor behavior that can react to both incoming messages and lifecycle signals. After spawning this actor from another actor (or as the guardian of an `akka.actor.typed.ActorSystem`) it will be executed within an `ActorContext` that allows access to the system, spawning and watching other actors, etc.
>
> This constructor is called immutable because the behavior instance does not need and in fact should not use (close over) mutable variables, but instead return a potentially different behavior encapsulating any state changes.