# Configure Dispatcher in Akka typed actors

Tags: java, scala, akka, akka-typed

I´m working with Akka typed, and I´m not able checking in the official documentation(https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/typed/actors.html#actors), which I found really short, how to configure the Dispatcher in the Actor typed.

Here an example of my code

```
private int actorTimeout = Integer.parseInt(getProperty("environment.actor.timeout", "10"));

    @Autowired
    private AkkaTypedDAO akkaTypedDAO;

    private ActorSystem<AkkaTypedDTO> system;

    @PostConstruct
    private void initActor() {
        system = ActorSystem.create(akkaTypedDAO.daoWithSupervisor, "AkkaTypedDAO");
    }

    private final Behavior<CommandAkkaTyped> service = Actor.immutable((ctx, msg) -> {
        sendToDAO(msg.id).thenApply(either -> {
            msg.replyTo.tell(either);
            return either;
        });
        return Actor.same();
    });

    public final Behavior<CommandAkkaTyped> serviceWithSupervisor = Actor.supervise(service).onFailure(Exception.class, restart());

    private CompletionStage<Either<ConnectorErrorVO, EntityDaoDTO>> sendToDAO(MUSIn<AkkaTypedPayLoad> id) {
        return AskPattern.ask(system,
                (ActorRef<Either<ConnectorErrorVO, EntityDaoDTO>> replyTo) -> new AkkaTypedDTO(new EntityDaoDTO(musIn), replyTo),
                new Timeout(actorTimeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS), system.scheduler());
    }
```

When I create my ActorSystem how can I configure the dispatcher for my Actor.immutable?

Answer (score 2):

You're using an outdated version of Akka Typed (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49901362/scala-syntactic-sugar/49903750#49903750) for more information about the history of the Akka Typed API). From the current version (as of this writing, 2.5.14) of the [Akka Typed documentation](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5.14/typed/actor-lifecycle.html#creating-actors):

> To specify a dispatcher when spawning an actor use [DispatcherSelector](https://doc.akka.io/japi/akka/2.5.14/?akka/actor/typed/DispatcherSelector.html). If not specified, the actor will use the default dispatcher, see [Default dispatcher](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5.14/dispatchers.html#default-dispatcher) for details.

```
public static final Behavior<Start> main =
  Behaviors.setup(context -> {
    final String dispatcherPath = "akka.actor.default-blocking-io-dispatcher";

    Props props = DispatcherSelector.fromConfig(dispatcherPath);
    final ActorRef<HelloWorld.Greet> greeter =
      context.spawn(HelloWorld.greeter, "greeter", props);

    return Behaviors.receiveMessage(msg -> {
      ActorRef<HelloWorld.Greeted> replyTo =
          context.spawn(HelloWorldBot.bot(0, 3), msg.name);
      greeter.tell(new HelloWorld.Greet(msg.name, replyTo));
      return Behaviors.same();
    });
  });
```